# Check multiple conditions in Stored Procedure on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

**Following my stored procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc_userlogin] @userid   VARCHAR(50),
                                       @password VARCHAR(50)
AS
    DECLARE @ReturnVal VARCHAR(500)

    SET nocount ON

    IF EXISTS(SELECT username,
                     password
              FROM   clients
              WHERE  username = @userid
                     AND password = Hashbytes('SHA1', @password))
      SET @ReturnVal='0|Logged in Successfully'
    ELSE IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT username
                  FROM   clients
                  WHERE  username = @userid)
      SET @ReturnVal='1|Incorrect Username'
    ELSE IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT username,
                         password
                  FROM   clients
                  WHERE  username = @userid
                         AND password = Hashbytes('SHA1', @password))
      SET @ReturnVal='1|Incorrect Password'

    SELECT @ReturnVal
```

In above Stored Procedure I am checking whether the username and password has been entered correctly.The issue that I was facing was checking multiple conditions.Can multiple select queries be eliminated and single select query in the If condition be used to check authentication?.Can the above Stored Procedure be customized to minimize the number of select statements within if conditions.

Please suggest

Thanks

Comment: Only check for success (i.e. only the first if). Why inform an attacker that he guessed a valid username? You might also leak personal data since anyone can find out if a username is in your system.

Comment: You're right @adrianm but my users wont be that much sophisticated

Comment: In most cases I find it easier to follow best practice than to spend time documenting to my customer why I don't. (You do tell your customer about the known security/privacy problem in the current code?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Optimize your SQL code to this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc_userlogin] @userid   VARCHAR(50),
                                       @password VARCHAR(50)
AS
    SET nocount ON

    DECLARE @ReturnVal VARCHAR(500)
    DECLARE @Password VARCHAR(50)
    SET @Password = NULL

    SELECT @Password = password
    FROM   clients
    WHERE  username = @userid

    IF ( @Password IS NULL )
      SET @ReturnVal='1|Incorrect Username'
    ELSE IF ( @Password = Hashbytes('SHA1', @password) )
      SET @ReturnVal='0|Logged in Successfully'
    ELSE
      SET @ReturnVal='1|Incorrect Password'

    SELECT @ReturnVal
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.If both username and password is wrong then ?

Comment: it is first condition **IF ( @Password IS NULL )**. because username doesn't exists so **@Password** is null

Comment: Getting this error

Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Proc_UserLogin, Line 0
Cannot assign a default value to a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Mohammad your solution worked but with some modifications

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Proc_CheckUser]
 @userid   VARCHAR(50),
 @password VARCHAR(50)
 AS
    SET nocount ON

    DECLARE @ReturnVal VARCHAR(500)
    DECLARE @PasswordOld VARCHAR(50)

    SELECT @PasswordOld = password
    FROM   Clients
    WHERE  username = @userid

    IF ( @PasswordOld IS NULL )
      SET @ReturnVal='1|Incorrect Username'
    ELSE IF ( @PasswordOld = Hashbytes('SHA1', @password) )
      SET @ReturnVal='0|Logged in Successfully'
    ELSE
      SET @ReturnVal='2|Incorrect Password'

SELECT @ReturnVal
```